# How to create refiner when we have two BCS external content crawled and displayed in Search?

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, bcs, refinement-panel

I am using SharePoint 2016 On-Premises Enterprise Search..I have two separate external contents in DB , each of the records having thousands of Data.

When the search results displayed I am trying to achieve refinement options available for me to select only BCS content 1 or BCS Content 2 or Local SharePoint results.

Is there any way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this answer. We have added Managed Property and then we did FULL CRAWL after that  , edited the Search Page--> Refiner Web Part and then added the custom Managed Property .

Now it is showing in Refiner web part when we search results.